# Banner slider setting code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slider

I have a slider on and I am not expert at javascript and jQuery I would like to set options into the slider like  "autoplay" true or false option, if i set true then it will work , if i set false "autoplay" will not work, same as "pager" true or false option, "navigation" true or false option.Any help with javascript or jQuery.Here is my slider: http://103.225.93.55/banner_plugins/
N.B: After loaded please refresh your browser again.

Comment: Hi, if you add a snippet of your HTML, CSS and JS we can help you, otherwise we have nothing to work with

Comment: If a understand well your question, you'd need some help with the spinner to make it dynamic. If so, I'd suggest to have a loot at http://codepen.io/hw/pen/biEBz, a comprehensive example of HTML+CSS+JavaScript is provided.